# Cut holes using boolean modifier without creating new faces

Tags: modifiers

How can I cut holes into a hollow cylindrical mesh using the boolean modifier and a UV sphere mesh?
I use the boolean modifier ('difference') and it leaves the hollow cylinder, but with the shape of the sphere being indented into it.

[image]

But what I actually want is the hollow cylinder with just a hole where the cylinder and the sphere intersected.
I feel like it has to do something with the orientation of the normals and I played around with that (for both objects) and at one point I think it actually worked but unfortunately I can't reproduce it.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm not free to choose the cutter object. It is yet to be created but it will be a bunch of rigid body spheres that are stacked on top of each other. And I wanna subtract those from the cylinder plane.

Comment: use a cylinder to cut the hole?

Comment: The single sphere was just for demonstrating purposes. In the end I actually need a more complex object (a random stack of spheres) to be the cutter object)

Comment: So boolean + selecting the faces overlapping with the cutter + removing those faces?

Answer (score 3):

Create a cylinder and a sphere, display the sphere as bounds for boolean visibility, add a vertex group to the cylinder (no need to assign vertices to the group), then add following modifiers to the cylinder:

(non-default settings marked with red rectangles)

[image] [image]

Comment: Does not work in Blender 3.3. Everything below the Boolean modifier has no useful effect at all.

Comment: @LissanroRayen I just checked on Blender 3.2 and 3.3 and it works for me. See answer edit and make sure you've set all the settings marked red.

Answer (score 2):

- Assign all vertices of cylinder to a vertex group
- Add boolean modifier and apply modifier
- Select > Select All by Trait > Ungrouped Vertices
- RMB > Separate > Selection

[image]